# GenericForeignKey with BaseDatatableView

Tags: django

I'm having trouble using a generic foreign key in `BaseDatatableView`.
I decided to use a generic foreign key in Django. In ORM I can do what I need, I can go through `content_object` to the instance that is connected to this field and easily read the field values of this instance. The problem occurs when I create tables using `BaseDatatableView`.

[models.py]

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.content_object.name} - {self.quantity}'
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['content_type', 'object_id'])
        ]

    
class Product1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tag = models.SlugField()
    note = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Product2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tag = models.SlugField()
    note = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

( The model architecture is exemplary and only tests relationships )

[views.py]

```
from django_datatables_view.base_datatable_view import BaseDatatableView

def warehouse_product1_all(request):
    return render(request, 'warehouse/product1_all.html')

class Product1WarehouseDataTable(BaseDatatableView):
    model = Warehouse
    columns = ['content_object__name', 'content_object__tag', 'content_object__note', 'quantity']

    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Product1)
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(content_type=ct)
        return qs
```

[urls.py]

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'warehouse'

urlpatterns = [

   path('products1/', views.warehouse_product1_all, name='product1_all'),

   path('product1_datatable_search/', views.Product1WarehouseDataTable.as_view(), name='product1_datatable_search'),

]
```

[warehouse/product1_all.html]

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card-body">
            <table id="my-datatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>    
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Tag</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
   
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/umd/simple-datatables.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>


    <script src="{% static 'js/warehouse/product1/objDataTable.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[js/warehouse/product1/objDataTable.js]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const table = $('#my-datatable').DataTable({
        'columns': [
            {'data': 'content_object__name'},
            {'data': 'content_object__tag'},
            {'data': 'content_object__note'},
            {'data': 'quantity'},
        ],
        'paging': true,
        'pageLength': 10,
        'lengthMenu': [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
        'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'ajax': {
            'url': '/warehouse/product1_datatable_search/'
        },
    });

});
```

`BaseDatatableView` throws an error:

> Field 'content_object' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

I want to display data from `Product1` in the table from the `Warehouse` model.

I've used `BaseDatatableView` before, but this is the first time I'm using generic keys.

Comment: I don't know `BaseDatatableView`. Please show its code or where you have imported it from. How else can we tell what's wrong?